# How to Configure dynamic value of Parallel session in liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

There is an oracle database in our project. We update oracle DB with liquibase. In our case we need to run an update query using liquibase. This query takes lot of time so we enabled parallel session for DML statment. We are looking for a way to make number of parallel session dynamic. Like in below query you see 15 as hardcoded values. Initially we thought we put this value to liquibase.properties file and we will pick it up from there but it is not possible in our case due to deployment constraint. Folks please let us know if you have any suggestions for us.

ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML PARALLEL 15;

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Dynamic SQL for this.
Below is a sample pseudo code

`Declare v_dop number; begin execute immediate 'alter session enable parallel dml';  execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML PARALLEL '||v_dop; end;`

V_Dop can be fetched from some configuration table